# width returns ok but height returns 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in angular inside my controller "myController" for calculating some points to paint image overlays:

```
    $scope.width = document.getElementById('imageId').clientWidth;
    $scope.image_height = document.getElementById('imageId').clientHeight;
  $(window).resize(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            //do something to update current scope based on the new innerWidth and let angular update the view.
            $scope.image_height = document.getElementById('imageId').clientHeight;
            $scope.image_width = document.getElementById('imageId').clientWidth;
            $scope.x = 20 - ((30 / 2) / $scope.image_width * 100);
            $scope.y = 30 - (30 / $scope.image_height * 100);
            $scope.x += '%';
            $scope.y += '%';
            console.log("x: " + $scope.x + "y: " + $scope.y);
        });
    });
```

And this html:

```
<div style="position:relative" ng-controller="myController">
    <div> <img id="imageId" src="mysrc" width="100%" height="100%"> </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:40%; top:20%;">
    </div>
</div>
width: {{width}} <br> height: {{image_height}}
```

The width is returned fine but the height always returns 0 until I resize my screen. I don't understand why clientWidth returns fine and clientHeight returns 0 until resizing. I tried on load, ng-init, document.ready... all the possibilities and none work....

Comment: The height of the img is effectively 0 until the moment of the image is "really" loaded. Maybe you should bind your calculation to the image load event like that : https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: And why is not the same with the width??

Comment: First, there's a mistake in your code : in one place you use image_width and in another width. That said, the width is OK and height is not because "100%" means 100% of the parent . the width of div is by default 100% of the container, so the width of your image will be 100% of this div. The height of the div 0, so 100% of 0 is 0. Try put an height to your div :) (And, yes, it's an oversimplification)

Comment: But i want a 100% height for this image, how can i do that ??

Comment: 100% of the height of the screen ? Of your document ? Of the parent ? Of the image ? For image, don't set any height or width, it the default behavior to be 100% of the image. If you wan't to stretch your image to 100% of your background, first look at background-size:cover if it doesn't do what you want, and second, set an height to your container. Search for a CSS solution before searching for a JavaScript one.

Comment: 100% of a colum 9 size responsive  bootstrap

Comment: a bootstrap column size is a width size (column 9 is roughly 75% of the container width), not a height size. If you want to hardcode your image height at "100%", you have to define explicitly the height of the parent.